# Keras: difference in flow from directory and own input

Tags: keras

I noticed a performance drop from around 10% in accuracy between what Keras gives as output and when I test it myself. So I reproduced this, see the small code snippet below. I generate input in two ways. input is generated by the Keras ImageGenerator (no augmentations) and input2 is produced without ImageGenerator.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import os
import pdb

def preprocess(img):
    img = image.array_to_img(img)
    width, height = img.size

    # Crop 48x48px
    desired_width, desired_height = 48, 48

    if width < 48:
        desired_width = width
    start_x = np.maximum(0, int((width-desired_width)/2))

    img = img.crop((start_x, np.maximum(0, height-desired_height), start_x+desired_width, height))
    img = img.resize((48, 48))

    img = image.img_to_array(img)
    return img / 255.

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=False,
    featurewise_std_normalization=False,
    preprocessing_function=preprocess)

generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'numbers_train', 
    target_size=(48,48),
    batch_size=1024, # Only 405 images in directory, so batch always the same
    classes=['02'],
    shuffle=False,
    class_mode='sparse')

inputs, targets = next(generator)

folder = 'numbers_train/02'
files = os.listdir(folder)
files = list(map(lambda x: os.path.join(folder, x), files))

images = []
for f in files:
    img = image.load_img(f)
    images.append(preprocess(img))
inputs2 = np.asarray(images)

print(np.mean(inputs))
print(np.mean(inputs2))
```

This gives two different values, where I expect that input and input2 are the same.

```
0.403158
0.41354
```

This causes a difference in accuracy of around 10%. What is happening here?

Edit: It seems to be something with the resizing of the images. Remove the img.resize in preprocess and add this line in the for loop before preprocessing and the means will be the same. But what I want is that the resizing is done after the cropping.

Edit2: So the ImageDataGenerator does first the resizing to (48,48) and then it calls the preprocess function. I want it the other way around. Does someone know a trick to do this?

Comment: That is still a lot of code where many things can go wrong. Can you boil it down a bit? For example, does `preprocess` need to perform all these steps to trigger the behavior?

Comment: preprocess is executed by both the Keras ImageGenerator and for the other way of generating the input. So that should not be the problem I think.

Comment: Okay, so remove it from your question and try to minimize your code even further. This will get you closer to the actual problem and increases the chances that somebody will be able to help you with this.

Comment: In the first case (called with flow_from_directory), images are first scaled to (48, 48) before `preprocess`. While in the 2nd case, images are `preprocess`ed directly. So training data would be different for the 2 cases.